# Можно ли назначить свой event если ui загружено через uic?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, uic

Начал использовать **`uic`** для загрузки интерфейса дабы уменьшить код и не путаться в строчках кода, но возникла проблема. 
Теперь мне не понятно как переопределить:
`mouseMoveEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent`, `mousePressEvent`.

Подскажите пожалуйста.

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
import sys


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = uic.loadUi()  #<---ваш путь до untitled.ui
        # self.ui.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)     #<---убирает стандартную рамку окна
        self.ui.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self._old_pos:
            return

        delta = event.pos() - self._old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Example()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

**untitled.ui**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>300</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Пример</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>100</width>
      <height>100</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>это типа окно</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# так -------------------------------------> vvvv
#        self.ui = uic.loadUi('q1422448.ui', self)
```

---

```
# или так :
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

# так -------------------------------------> vvvv
#        self.ui = uic.loadUi('q1422448.ui', self)             # <--- ваш путь до untitled.ui
#        self.ui.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) 

# или так 
        uic.loadUi('q1422448.ui', self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self._old_pos:
            return

        delta = event.pos() - self._old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Example()
    ui.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все понял, спасибо!

Comment: @Kickwall пожалуйста.